# How to change MediaCodec encoding bitrate on the fly while streaming in Android?

Tags: android, video-encoding, android-mediacodec, android-mediarecorder

I want to change the **encoding bitrate** including **H264 and AAC** by Android `MediaCodec` dynamically , according to the current network.

How to update the encoding bitrate in Android `MediaCodec` dynamically ?

PS: I found `PARAMETER_KEY_VIDEO_BITRATE` and `setParameters` is available on API 19

**[PARAMETER_KEY_VIDEO_BITRATE](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#PARAMETER_KEY_VIDEO_BITRATE)**

> Change a video encoder's target bitrate on the fly. The value is an Integer object containing the new bitrate in bps.
>
> Constant Value: "video-bitrate"

**[setParameters](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#setParameters(android.os.Bundle))**

> Communicate additional parameter changes to the component instance.
>
> Throws
> IllegalStateException   if in the Uninitialized state.

Is there any way to do it under API 19 ?

Comment: @fadden Could you please give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Stopping the Codec, setting the parameters and restarting it worked for me.

Comment: Why not? I think its not possible to change the bitrate without stopping the encoder.

Comment: I think too. So i hope someone can ensure it.

Answer (score 4):

Your format needs to support adaptive bitrate. Eg. I was able to set the bitrate using the following. Make sure you're in api 19 or above though.I was encoding the H264 frames into an FLV container.

`Bundle bitrate = new Bundle();
            bitrate.putInt(MediaCodec.PARAMETER_KEY_VIDEO_BITRATE, targetBitrate);
            mEncoder.setParameters(bitrate);`